# How to target a jQuery object by value, not by index

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

Here some of my code:

```
var fashion = [];

/* LEVEL 1 CATEGORIES */
fashion.push({ level1 : 'Mens', inner:[] });
fashion.push({ level1 : 'Womens', inner:[] });
```

I am trying to then push a value into the `inner` array, only for the `Mens` category.
I can write:

```
/* LEVEL 2 CATEGORIES */
fashion[0].inner.push({ level2 : 'Shoes' });
fashion[0].inner.push({ level2 : 'Accessories'});
```

But i want to target it **not by index 0**, but by the "Mens" value.
Is there a way of doing that?
So it becomes something like:

```
fashion['Mens'].inner.push({ level2 : 'Shoes'});
```

but this syntax is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, this works, I was hoping not to use loops, however...

Comment: without using loop you are not able to push values to all element in array .

Answer (score 1):

There is no jQuery object in your code. A jQuery object is an object that is returned by jQuery constructor (`$()`). You have a simple JavaScript array of objects. For filtering the array element you can use the `Array.prototype.filter` method:

```
fashion.filter(function(el) {
   return el.level1 === 'Mens';
})[0].inner.push({ level2 : 'Shoes' });
```

`filter` returns an array of matching elements. So you should either iterate through the returned array (using `Array.prototype.forEach` method) or use the bracket notation for getting the target object by index. It should be noted that `filter` will return an empty array where is no matching element, so it would better to check the `length` property of the returned array before using bracket notation.

Answer (score 0):

you could use jquery each loop

```
$.each(fashion, function( index, value ) {
  if(value.level1 === 'Mens') {  // specify your condition 
     value.inner.push({ level2 : 'Shoes' });
     // your code to push value
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using javascript `for` loop.

```
 var fashion = [];
 fashion.push({ level1 : 'Mens', inner:[] });
 fashion.push({ level1 : 'Womens', inner:[] });

  console.log(fashion);

 for(i=0;i<fashion.length;i++){
   if(fashion[i].level1 == "Mens"){
     fashion[i].inner.push({ level2 : 'Shoes' });
     fashion[i].inner.push({ level2 : 'Accessories'});
   }
 }

console.log(fashion);
```

Check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/ycpj5fcy/)

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution is to change fashion and inner into objects:

```
var fashion = {};

/* LEVEL 1 CATEGORIES */
fashion.Mens.inner = {};
fashion.Womens.inner = {};

/* LEVEL 2 CATEGORIES */
fashion.Mens.inner.Shoes = [];
fashion.Mens.inner.Accessories = [];
```